Matching different objects with id field in different array map
I want to map X array and return a component. The component has a string prop but not in the same array. I want to find in object Y array who match with X.symbolId
const X = [
{
id: 1,
symbolId: 2,
},
{
id: 2,
symbolId: 3,
},
{
id: 3,
symbolId: 3,
},
{
id: 3,
symbolId: 2,
},
]

const Y = [
{
id: 1,
symbol: "USD",
name: "Dollar",
},
{
id: 2,
symbol: "EUR",
name: "Euro"
},
{
id: 3,
symbol: "GLD",
name: "Gold"
}
]

I have this 2 array. I want to map X and find Y object with symbolID.
X.map((a)=> {
return (
<Text>{Y.find((b) => b.id === a.symbolId).name}</Text>
)
})

What I Expected is ;
<Text>Euro</Text>
<Text>Gold</Text>
<Text>Gold</Text>
<Text>Euro</Text>

But find method just control first object and return undefined for others. Is there any different method for this?

Why is Dollar the last <Text> component? Shouldn't it be Euro? Also, at the start of your question you say " I want to find every object Y array who match with X.id", but then later you say you want to match with symbolID, so your question isn't very clear.

I've been dealing with this for a while now, I think I need some rest. I'm sorry I missed it.
